# Can I dynamically insert a method in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, database, html

```
    var which = {};
    which['creditcards'] = "tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM " + table + " ', [], querySucess, errorCB)";

     db.transaction(function(tx){
        which[table];

    });
```

I want to be able to dynamically insert the select statement based on the variable clicked. Is this possible? Am I going about it the right way?

Comment: it isn't good idea let see the queries at the client side, do not have a way to put it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but no, you don't appear to be going about it the right way - I'd expect something more like the following:

```
function dbQueryWrapper(table) { // table is a string supplied from onclick etc
    db.transaction (
        function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM ?;', [ table ], querySucess, errorCB
            );
        }
    );
}
```

The second param with the [] is an array of stuff you want to pass into your query - each item fills on ? in the query

Comment: You cannot pass a column/table name as a bind parameter in WebSQL/SQLite.

Comment: Bear in mind that jdurango is correct though - for security reasons it's a very bad idea to allow your queries to be seen by users. using parameters (the ? + variable combination) is also always advised to avoid malicious sql injection

Comment: no one sees my queries at all its very secure i actually just want to be able to insert on a diff table depending on the page they are on

Comment: the insert is wokring right but i need the append to be dynamic and i dont want to use case statements or if statements